# SOAP Service - crossed wires with responses during simultaneous requests?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm having a strange issue with one of our SOAP web services.

For some background information - we have about 100-110 different locations with multiple terminals that at some point will probably hit this particular endpoint - let's call it **Endpoint1**.  What **Endpoint1** does is call a web service for one of our partners, then a couple of database queries in our own systems to verify that the item that was scanned is actually at the location it says it was from, some fraud-prevention code, etc. that isn't too relevant to the question at hand.  Calls to **Endpoint1** generally take anywhere from 5-20 seconds depending on the internet connection from the location calling it, usually towards the lower end of that range.

The issue is that when two or more locations are making simultaneous or near-simultaneous calls to **Endpoint1**, the responses that some of the locations receive back are incorrect - specifically, they are the responses that should be going to one of the other locations.

E.g.

- Location A sends identifier *11235813* at the same time that
  location B sends identifier *21345589*.  Location A is expecting
  information back on the item with that serial number, and Location B
  is expecting the same for its serial number.  What actually ends up
  happening is either Location A receives the information for Location
  B's item, or vice versa.

This has happened multiple times over the past week since we wide deployed a system update to all locations.  When we logged exactly what was being sent by **Endpoint1** to the partner web service, sometimes the identifier sent would be completely incorrect - i.e. it would log Location A as having sent identifier *21345589* despite the logs from Location A showing it as having sent *11235813*.  Other times, it would show as *11235813* being sent, but the response would be the information for *21345589* from the partner web service.

This SOAP service is deployed in IIS8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2. It is written in .NET v4.5 but the application pool .NET CLR version is 4.0.  Only one server is running this code - there are no additional servers or load balancing.

---

Here is the relevant beginning part of the code for **Endpoint1**.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true, Description = "Endpoint1")]
        public service.Endpoint1ResponseObject Endpoint1(string param1, string param2, string Identifier, string param3,string locationNo, 
            string param4, string param5, string param6, string param7, string param8,string param9,
            string param10, string param11)
        {
            ...    
            service.Endpoint1ResponseObject response = new service.Endpoint1ResponseObject();
            try
            {
                response.SubObj1 = new service.SubObj1();
                response.SubObj2 = new service.SubObj2();
                response.SubObj3 = new service.SubObj3();
                response.SubObj4 = new service.SubObj4();
                if (//Identifier length/format validation)
                {
                    if (CheckParams(param1, param2))
                    {

                        Functional fn = new Functional();
                        locationNo = fn.CheckValidLocationNo(locationNo);
                        response.subObj4.Property1 = "";
                        Partner.PartnerRequest(locationNo, Identifier.Trim(), param3, param4, param5, param6, ref response);
                            ...etc.
```

All of the response subobjects and the response object itself are instantiated at the beginning of **Endpoint1** - there are no static variables or class-level variables in the main class that contains this function.  The class definitions are part of the "service" class - these are all declared public and are not static.  Sometimes, only **subObj4**'s information is wrong (the partner web service information), sometimes all four subobjects have the incorrect information.  I have not noticed a pattern yet.

### My question is

- what possible cause is there for requests to be seemingly overwriting variables/parameters for other concurrent requests happening simultaneously? How can I fix the issue?

---

If more information is needed I will be happy to provide what I can - several different people have worked on this code by this point.

### Things I have tried

1. Setting the application pool as a web garden with 5 worker threads (did not work)
2. removing all logging to file from Endpoint1. The theory was that multiple requests writing to one file at once was causing the issues. This was a short while ago so I'm not sure whether the problem has happened again, as it depends on how many transactions are occurring at our locations at any given point in time (update: this did not work either)

Comment: As an addendum - the two things I have tried are: Setting the application pool as a web garden with 5 worker threads (did not work), and removing all logging to file from **Endpoint1**.  The theory was that multiple requests writing to one file at once was causing the issues.  This was a short while ago so I'm not sure whether the problem has happened again, as it depends on how many transactions are occurring at our locations at any given point in time.

Comment: I've incorporated your addendum into your post.  Normally that's how we do things rather than commenting on our own posts.   Welcome and good luck! :)

Comment: This sounds like a Race Condition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software). And those are propably the trickiest bug to solve. Unfortunately they are also the kind of bugs only indept knowledge of the Code and Execution order can fix.

Comment: My best idea is that it might be what I call a "Index Race Condition". You can never use a indexed collection (array, List) thread save. If you add or remove anything, what used to be Index 5 could suddenly be at index 4 or 6. Key/Value pair collections tend to be less vulnerable, if you can avoid repetitive keys reliably. Back with .NET 4.0 they added a bunch of Concurrent Colelctions. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) You will not find any indexed ones among them and I asume that is the case.

Comment: MickyD - sorry bout that, couldn't find the edit button for the post and I've been tearing my hair out over this all day.  Cheers!


@Christopher I was worried it might be that - I always sort of assumed that web services like this would have separate instances handling each request but I'm not sure why they would need to overwrite the variables in each other if they were actually separate threads.  However, there aren't any indexed items in any of the variables (to my knowledge, as I'm not currently at work anymore) and none of the parameters are indexed unless i'm missing something

Comment: @ZhangC1459: In high performance Multithreaded Environment, you can not even asume that one task will be worked on *by the same thread* for it's entire lifetime. Once you put in any delay or asynch operation, the thread might get something else to do and never see that task again.

Comment: @Christopher: We don't have any delays or async operations in Endpoint1 - one of the things that was discussed was whether making it async would fix the issue, lol.  It was determined that it probably wouldn't and it'd be a last-ditch solution if nothing else worked.

Comment: If anything, you should go the opposite route. Make it "Single Processing at a time". You can still receive requests and send answer asynchronously. But if you make the processing (querying the other service) purely singlethreaded it might work. But this is a webservice, so I do not know how to properly bottleneck it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to go about that either - as far as I'm aware, SOAP services cannot be queued in that fashion.  Thanks for the help though!